# Can't save video to Parse in swift

Tags: swift, video, parse-platform

I am simply trying to have the user take a short video in the application, and when the video is recorded, the app would send it to the Parse back-end once the user clicks 'Use Video' using `UIImagePickerController`.

I am able to save the video locally in the `idFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` with

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathString!, self, nil, nil)
```

But I can't find anything online to save the video to Parse.

The line that that is running the error is

```
let videoFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: videoData)
```

With error handler - `Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'NSData'`

I believe it has something to do with this line above it causing the error:

```
let videoData = tempImage.relativePath
```

I can't find code to get it working. Any help would me amazing!

```
@IBAction func recordAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {

    print("Camera Avilable")

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 180 // Perhaps reduce 180 to 120
        imagePicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityType.TypeMedium
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        print("Camera Unavailable")

    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
    let pathString = tempImage.relativePath
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


    let videoData = tempImage.relativePath
    let videoFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: videoData)

    PFUser.currentUser()?.setObject(videoFile, forKey: "videoFile")
    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let videoData = NSData(contentsOfFile:tempImage.relativePath)

let videoFile:PFFile = PFFile(name:"yourfilenamewithtype", data:videoData)

file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({(succeeded:Bool,error:NSError?)

//Handle success or failure here.

},progressBlock:{(percentDone: Int32) -> Void in

//Update your progress spinner here.percentDone will be between 0 and 100.

})

yourfilenamewithtype like this,resume.txt

The method is the try to make file to NSdata.

Comment: The output says save is successful now but I don't see any data saved in parse? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552158/video-is-not-saving-in-parse

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Parse, but the [documentation](http://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html) suggests that the `PFFile(data:)` constructor indeed expects the contents of the file, and you give the name. You likely want to use `PFFile(name: nil, contentsAtPath: pathString!)`.

Note that you set `pathString` and `videoData` to the same value, which is the path and not the data.

More importantly, note that if you simply load the file with `NSData(contentsOfFile: pathString!)` as RYANCOAL9999 suggested, you are putting the entire video file into RAM. You could use `NSData(contentsOfFile: pathString!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)`, but I believe it's best to simply delegate the entire file copying process to the libraries.